# Liip imagine bundle not working - Symfony -lighttpd

Tags: symfony, lighttpd, liipimaginebundle

when I upload the file, lip not working 
if I use the commande

```
php-cgi bin/console liip:imagine:cache:resolve uploads/image/5c0e41b61ca0c252450232.png
```

this is work

this the conf for lighttpd

```
url.rewrite-once = (
"^/(.*)\.(.*)" => "/public/$0",
"^/media/cache/.*\.(eot|woff|ttf|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|)$" =>           "/public/index.php/$1" ,
"^/assets/fonts/.*\.(eot|woff|ttf|woff2|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|)$" =>   "$0",
"^/([^.]+)$" => "/public/index.php/$1",
```

"^/$" => "/public/index.php"
  )

do you have a idea ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

the solution

```
url.rewrite-once = (
"^/[^\?]+(\?.*)?/media/cache/resolve/.*\.   (eot|woff|ttf|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|)$" => "/public/index.php/$1" ,
"^/(.*)\.(.*)" => "/public/$0",
"^/([^.]+)$" => "/public/index.php/$1",
 "^/$" => "/public/index.php"
)
```